# How to send request to all connected clients in Websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am quite new to Websocket Communication and Node.js. Can anyone help me how to send request to all clients connected through Websocket.

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');
socket.on('user_in', function (data){
        console.log(data);
        socket.send("Hi All");
  });

  socket.on('user_out', function (data){
        console.log(data);
        socket.send("Hi All");
  });

  socket.on('to_all', function (data){
        console.log(data);
        socket.send("Hi All");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to broadcast messages from a Socket.IO client to all other clients. As far as I know that can't be done, but you can do it from the server:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        io.emit('message', message);
    });

});
```

There's a good example [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).